# Divergent series and monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a non-negative sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n= 0$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n = \infty$.

Is it true that there exists a monotone sub-sequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum_{k \geq 1}a_{n_k} = \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. My counterexample sequence is broken into contiguous blocks, where the $k^{th}$ block is an arithmetic progression of length $2^k+1$ starting at $2^{-k}$ and ending at $2^{-k+1}$. This looks  like
$$
\frac12, \frac34, 1, \quad \frac14,\frac5{16},\frac38,\frac{7}{16},\frac12, \quad \frac18,\frac{5}{64},\frac{3}{32},\dots,\frac14,\quad \dots 
$$
We have $a_n\to 0$, and clearly $\sum a_n=\infty$ since the sum of each block is more than $1$. However, any monotone subsequence must have at most $1$ entry from each block, so its sum is bounded by $1+(1/2)+(1/4)+\dots=2$.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!